# boost::python::list length

Tags: c++, list, boost, boost-python

Is there any way to calculate length of list passed from python to C++? I want do do
something like this, but list class lacks `length` (or anything similar) method:

```
class Awesome{
  public:
    void awesomeMethod(const boost::python::list& list_of_something){
      list_of_something.length() // suprisingly there's no such method
    } 
};
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[Like Python](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#len), you should use the [free function `len()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/python/doc/html/reference/object_wrappers/boost_python_object_hpp.html#object_wrappers.boost_python_object_hpp.example) to get the length. Try

```
boost::python::len(list_of_something)
```

Answer (score 2):

It's called `len`, not `length`, and it's not a method but a free-standing function (Python does not use `length` methods, but length protocol and `len()` function).

```
return boost::python::len(list_of_something);
```